# usort not working for laravel multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.3, usort

I have an array

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 79
                    [name] => shelin
                    [status] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 80
                    [name] => shanu
                    [status] => 2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 81
                    [name] => linto
                    [status] => 2
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 82
                    [name] => joseph
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

I want to rearrange this array by status desc order
I try

```
usort($usersdetailsA, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->status <=> $b->status;
});
```

I got an error like

> usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

I tried 
 $usersdetailsA = $this->$usersdetailsA->getValues();
the i got an error like

> Undefined property:
>   TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\Users::$[{"id":79,"name":"shelin","status":0},{"id":80,"name":"shanu","status":"2"},{"id":81,"name":"linto","status":"2"},{"id":82,"name":"joseph","status":0}]

Expected output

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 80
                        [name] => shanu
                        [status] => 2
                    )
 [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 81
                        [name] => linto
                        [status] => 2
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 79
                        [name] => shelin
                        [status] => 0
                    )



                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 82
                        [name] => joseph
                        [status] => 0
                    )
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortby) with [sort](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortbydesc) methods by a given key:

```
$sorted = $collection->sortByDesc('status');
```