# Issue with foreach Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

This Question is continuation of [My first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149459/usort-not-working-for-laravel-multidimensional-arrays/52149555#52149555)

So I have an array

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 79
                    [name] => shelin
                    [status] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 80
                    [name] => shanu
                    [status] => 2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 81
                    [name] => linto
                    [status] => 2
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 82
                    [name] => joseph
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

I sort this array

```
$sorted = $collection->sortByDesc('status');
```

my view

```
return view('voyager::users.viewusersAppraisals')->with('values', $sorted);
```

Now, I got array like

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 81
                        [name] => linto
                        [status] => 2
                    )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 80
                    [name] => shanu
                    [status] => 2
                )

            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 79
                    [name] => shelin
                    [status] => 0
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 82
                    [name] => joseph
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

and my `foreach` loop

```
 @foreach($values as $data)<?php

?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$data->name}}</td>



                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

I expect output like so

```
linto
shanu
shelin
joseph
```

But I get output like so

```
 joseph 
linto 
shanu 
shelin
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: share how you pass `$values` from controller to view ?

Comment: you might be using the unsorted one, double check.

Comment: there is a mistake for $values.. please double check if the $values is update or not after sort

Comment: If your sorted array is stored in `$sorted`, then why are you using `$values` in `foreach`?

Comment: @linuxartisan i have update my question..please check

Comment: with('values', $sorted); controller to view

Comment: @Wreigh I have updated myquestion ..please help me

Comment: i believe, you need to sort it by `status` desc and later with `name` asc.

Answer (score 1):

It must be your variable be getting overwritten somewhere in the code which you have not mentioned.

Also please dd($sorted) your result after executing the eloquent query to see whether you are getting data from db in right format as per your need.